# Is there a way to have two colorAxis in highcharts heatmap?

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to have support two color axis on one heatmap? For example, make half of the heatmap to have a gradient from white to **blue**, and the other half of the heatmap to have a gradient from white to **red**.

Here is an example of a heatmap with only 1 color axis:
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is **no** - Highcharts supports only one color axis per chart.

Anyway, you can share the idea of adding that functionality to Highcharts here: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api

Comment: is it possible until now?

Comment: It's still not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Since Highcharts v7.2.0 you can use multiple color axis for almost all series types:

```
colorAxis: [{
    ...,
    maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
}, {
    maxColor: '#ff1100'
}]
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vLocpmra/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis

**Blog:** https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/color-coded-data/